# Reading rtf information from entity entries to NSString

Tags: objective-c, core-data, rtf, nsdata, binary-data

I have an entity (named Song) that one of the Attributes is binary data (a rtf field) that I use to to store chord charts or notes about a song.  I need to be able to print this field along with the other string fields of this entity.  I have tried every permutation of this I can think of:

```
NSString* notesString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithRTF:[object valueForKey:@"cueNotes"] documentAttributes:nil] autorelease];
```

I have been successfull parsing the  `[object valueForKey:@"cueNotes"] to NSData and seeing the rtf formated data, but when I try initWithRTF I get a null result.

Here is an example of a log of the entity that I'm pulling this Data from:

```
2010-10-30 00:47:32.867 lzshow7.2[4222:10b] <NSManagedObject: 0x2a4850> (entity: Song; id: 0x26a030 <x-coredata:///Song/t172F066B-285C-4125-B2FA-CFFA6A353D102> ; data: {
cueName = Stupid;
cueNo = 001;
cueNotes = <040b7479 70656473 74726561 6d8103e8 84014084 84840d4e 534d7574 61626c65 44617461 00848406 4e534461 74610084 8408>;
songToEffect =     (
);
songToInstrument =     (
);

})
```

Any help that anyone could provide would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

initWithRTF: is a method of NSAttributedString; NSString won't respond to that selector and will return nil, so you have to just change the class name to fix this problem.

Your compiler must have warned you there - I would advise you not to ignore compiler warnings, it saves a lot of trouble.

Also, nil should be only used in place for id - since this is not the case for the document attributes you ought to use NULL there instead.

Comment: Ok, I did start with NSAttributedString without any luck, I changed it back as per your suggestion, this time I also changed the nil to NULL and after passing this:  NSAttributedString* notesString = [[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithRTF:[object valueForKey:@"cueNotes"] documentAttributes:NULL] autorelease];
NSLog(@"notes are:  %n", notesString);  I got this back from the Log:  notes are:      
Bummer...Any thoughts????  Do I need to convert the Attributed string to NSString???

Comment: I guess your NSLog statement is a typo, as it should be %@, not %n. I have never worked with NSAttributedString, so I don't know what it's description is - maybe you need to log [notesString string]?

Comment: your right the %n should be a %@... I changed that and changed to  [notesString string]... Then got:  notes are:  (null)  Thoughts?